# Can't Enum.map on Elixir List

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to run `Enum.map` on a regular list to round all values:

```
$ iex                                                                                                                    
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Interactive Elixir (1.4.0) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> l = [80.308, 87.857, 90.94, 94.022, 100]
[80.308, 87.857, 90.94, 94.022, 100]
iex(2)> Enum.map l, &Kernel.round/1 
'PX[^d'
iex(3)>
```

Any idea why am I getting this result back?

Comment: `'PX[^d' == [80, 88, 91, 94, 100] #=> true`. Everyone trips on this once when learning Elixir. :)

Comment: Thanks I guess I'm no exception :)

Comment: When ever you are confused by a result in iex, use the i command to see what it actually is.